# Hive error : java.io.IOException: Couldn't create proxy provider class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-streaming

I have hive query which run successful sometimes but maximum time gives an error "java.io.IOException: Couldn't create proxy provider class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider"

Below is my error log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Couldn't create proxy
>   provider class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.Con\
>   figuredFailoverProxyProvider  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.isSplitable(CombineFileInputFormat.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getMoreSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:283)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:435)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:517)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:399)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:564)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:559)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:559)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:550)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:136)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1516)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1283)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1101)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:924)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:914)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:269)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:431)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:464)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:474)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:756)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:694)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:633)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Couldn't create proxy provider class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverPr\
>   oxyProvider   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createFailoverProxyProvider(NameNodeProxies.java:475)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:148)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:632)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:570)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.isSplitable(CombineFileInputFormat.java:151)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createFailoverProxyProvider(NameNodeProxies.java:458)
>     ... 53 more Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit
>   exceeded  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:242)  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:216)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:208)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:440)   at
>   java.lang.String.split(String.java:2288)  at
>   sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(IPAddressUtil.java:47)
>     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1129)     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil$StandardHostResolver.getByName(SecurityUtil.java:474)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getByName(SecurityUtil.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddrForHost(NetUtils.java:235)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:215)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:163)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.getAddressesForNameserviceId(DFSUtil.java:677)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.getAddressesForNsIds(DFSUtil.java:645)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.getAddresses(DFSUtil.java:628)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.getHaNnRpcAddresses(DFSUtil.java:727)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.(ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.java:88)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createFailoverProxyProvider(NameNodeProxies.java:458)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:148)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:632)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:570)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169) Job
>   Submission failed with exception
>   'java.lang.RuntimeException(java.io.IOException: Couldn't create proxy
>   provider class org.apac\
>   he.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider)'

Could anyone tell me why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across a similar exception myself, and increasing the hive client heap didn't help. I found I was able to clear up the OutOfMemory GC Overhead exception by adding a partition column to the where clause of the query, so I've concluded that having a very large number of splits is causing this exception. I haven't dug into the code, but I believe I've seen this happen with string concatenation in a loop triggering gc thrashing, and something similar might be happening in the CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits method.